# Apparently java doesn't have the same nashorn.jar for Linux and Windows

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn

I'm trying to configure my workspace from windows in linux.

This code which is OK in windows:

```
jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser p = new jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser(s, null);
```

gets the following error under linux:

`constructor JSONParser in class JSONParser cannot be applied to different types`

And when I look at the source code under Linux and at the source code under Windows, I see very clear that the same class is different.

*Does anyone know why this?* If so, WORA principle isn't applied here, which seems pretty confusing to me.

Comment: You shouldn't be using internal classes directly like that.

Comment: Are you using the same java version in both environments?

Comment: "WORA principle isn't applied here" that's for the users of the language, not for internal JDK stuff

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca Yes. Java 1.8.0_241 on linux and 1.8.0_20 on Windows.

Comment: Do you need a JS runtime at all? If all you need to do is get a JSON parser, there are plenty of options.

Comment: @Thilo I didn't write the code. I try to configure my workspace in Linux.

Comment: Those are different JDK/JRE versions (I'm not sure what difference you're seeing between the two, may be minor, may be not). Also, are they from the same vendor (i.e. both from oracle or both from azul or...)

Comment: You'll have to fix that code otherwise it won't run on different JDK versions.

Comment: It seems the internet is full of tutorials teaching poor unsuspecting people to use `jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser` for parsing JSON. You should switch to a more suitable parser and leave Nashorn for the scripting engine.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes, they are both from Oracle. I'll try to get the closest one to Windows on LInux. Thanks.

Comment: @artaxerxe so instead of doing the sane thing that everyone is recommending, you're trying to keep using the same internal classes, ensuring that in the future you'll probably encounter the same problem? Are you really sure about that?

Comment: There are more than five years between these versions. Besides that, continuing using this class *will* break in future versions.

Comment: @Kayaman, Holger I didn't write the project! I just try to configure it in order to be able to start and work on it. I think is too early to start and talk what too modify in it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kayaman the OP will not encounter “the same problem” in the future. The future waiting problems are a) the encapsulation which started in Java 9 will be finished and the class become entirely inaccessible and b) the scripting engine will (again) get replaced by an entirely different engine. Whichever happens first.

Comment: @Holger yeah I didn't actually expect there to be a breaking change (or them having a version update) in v8, but Jigsaw messing that up did come to mind. I just wanted to paint devils on the walls ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hints given by different users, especially @FedericoklezCulloca, I managed to fix my problem. I would state the following points bellow:

1. Use only "exposed" interface from Java API and avoid using restricted one.
2. I had to get exactly the same version of JDK (the same vendor, of course) in linux. Than it worked.